# Could I use just one BroadcastReceiver in my android app?

Tags: android

I am kind of confused about the BroadcastReceiver.
As title, I don't think I need another one BroadcastReceiver in my app.

Or, is there something wrong if I use a bunch of BroadcastReceiver in my app?
I think it  will affect my OS execute memory and performance, am I right.

Thank you for your time and hot-heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all up to you. You can have multiple `BroadcastReceiver` for different sets of `intent-filter` or use single broadcast receiver to handle all the intent-filters.

Usually its better to define different receivers based on the set of intent-filters which are supposed to offer functionality for a related group of task.

Like I said, its all up to you. If you have a large set of intent-filters and you want your code to be handled properly (based on the similar classification of tasks it performs) then go for multiple receivers. Otherwise its easy and logical to handle few filters in single receiver.

Moreover, the performance of your app will not be obstructed as it depends on the execution of tasks with in the receiver, not the quantity of receivers or filters.

Tip: Try to introduce `Threads` wherever you are expected to perform some heavy lifting :)

Comment: Thank you Waqas~~ That is my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's considered that class should have one responsibility. So, if your BroadcastReceiver handles both `SMS` and `CALL` intents, then consider having multiple receivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare as many BroadcastReceivers as you want on your app. It will affect if on every broadcast you receive you start doing a million long running background operations.

But does the app you're planning really need all those receivers?

There're some APIs to programmatically enable/disable your declared receivers, might be a good option too.

**edit:**
I guess it would be easier if you do a little test yourself.

- On your Eclipse, create a new Android Project.
- Create a class that extends the BroadcastReceiver.
- Save and close it.
- Now go to the manifest, Application tab, Application Nodes, ADD button, Add a receiver.
- Wait for the Eclipse to search your application and find the one you just created.
- Inside the receiver put a new Intent Filter. Don't need name or anything.
- Inside the filter put an Action.
- In the action name, check the drop-down menu.

Those are ALL the different actions a BroadcastReceiver might be receiving. So it just make it simpler and more organized for some application to implements more than one receiver, one receiver for each different type of action. Or maybe it's only receiving two very similar actions and it's simpler to make it all in one receiver.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you Bundius.I steal don't understand Why people use one more BroadcastReceiver in their APPs?